# Prepend string to lines in org source block export?

Tags: org-export

I would like to prepend a $ sign to the front of every non empty line in the export. Comments should be skipped if possible. Couldn't find an option for it.

Is there an option? If not is there a quick way to achieve that with some elisp?

Comment: Is the $ the comment sign of the source?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm No, the source is a sh(shell) block.

Comment: I see, did you had a look at export filters http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html ?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm Thanks for the pointer. Seems like this is the right way to solve this. I will look into that.

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm Thanks, it worked. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some elisp hacking, this seems to work:

```el
(defun my-add-dollar-sign (text backend info)
  "Add a dollar sign to the shell export blocks in html exports"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert text)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (search-forward "<pre class=\"src src-sh\">")
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region (point)
                          (save-excursion
                            (search-forward "</pre>")
                            (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                            (point)))
        (while (not (eobp))
          (unless (or (looking-at
                       (concat "<span style=\"color: "
                               (face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face :foreground)
                               ";\">"))
                      (looking-at "[[:space:]]*$"))
            (insert "$ "))
          (forward-line 1)))
      (buffer-string))))



(require 'ox)
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
             'my-add-dollar-sign)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#+begin_src shell :noweb yes :tangle somefile.sh
  $ <<prefix-stuff>>
#+end_src

#+name: prefix-stuff
#+begin_src shell
  thing-you-wanted-prefixed-here
  with-as-many-lines-as-you-like
#+end_src
```

Export with `C-x v t`. If you use noweb, orgmode will repeat the prefix for all the lines in the sub-block.